# What counts as projects on my resume?

Tags: resume, projects

I am a senior CS student trying to build my resume. Right now I only have one-semester work experience on campus that was related to CS. Unfortunately, I could not get an internship. Many companies I talked to just told me they cannot hire me because I am an international student.

In order to make my resume look better, I have been working on side projects, and I want someone on here to clarify what exactly counts as projects.

I have made a mini poker game spending a few days, but is it worth mentioning it on my resume? 
Or does a project on resume have to be a-month-long or a-few-month-long work?

Can you tell me what could be a good project to mention on the resume?
Also what do you think shohld be mentioned regarding the project? The project name, date of completion? Or how long it took to make the project? Brief description of the project? Does the project have to be accessible to public (like github etc)?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, mention that. It's better than nothing. It's better still if you post its code publicly on github. And it would be better still if you have longer projects to talk about, then you'll be able to remove that one, but until then, you don't have much of a choice. Just be prepared to answer the question of how much of the project was supplied by the school and how much of it you did on your own. Just include a brief description and a date. The point of the resume is to get to the interview.

Answer (score 8):

Anything that demonstrates knowledge and skills that you have learned, either in the classroom or on your own, can be considered a project. It can be your contributions to a larger project or a project that is entirely your own, but it should be clear what your level of involvement is. If you put a project on your resume, you should be able to show code (if that's possible) and discuss various aspects about the work - the design, technical challenges, things that went well, things that didn't go well, things that you learned.

If you have one or more interesting projects, you can put them on your resume and put a brief summary of what the project is, when you worked on it, your level of involvement, and the technologies that you used to implement it. If the project is accessible to the public, you can put a link to the public repository as well.

However, if the reason for being rejected was that you are an international student, having projects on your resumes won't help that. You need to find companies that are capable of hiring you. If you need help, most universities have a career services department that can provide guidance.

Answer (score 0):

> What counts as projects on my resume?

**Whatever the most interesting projects or significant accomplishments you have, that support your intended message, and fit on your resume.**

Someone who is more senior in his/her career will have completed more projects and more large projects than someone who's just starting out. This is in part reflected by what they chop off their resume *in order to make room for* the more significant accomplishments they want the potential future employer to focus on.

Think about what message you are trying to convey by including each item on your resume.  Each element should help the reader understand something about you, ideally something you want them to understand about you.

So, first think about what message you want to send, and then figure out what information from your background / experience can help send it.  (When coming up with the first part, be sure to consider what messages your background / experience *can* send and whether or not you want to include those possibilities).

For example, are you trying to show that you're a self-starter who takes initiative and can do things on your own without super-specific direction?  Are you trying to show that you enjoy programming so much that you do it in your "free" time without any specific external incentive? If so, some of these smaller projects might be useful in sending the message.

Are you trying to show that you're good with software architecture and project management?  Or, that you're a good team player?  Individual coding projects on the scale of a few days aren't likely to help with that, but you might have other experiences and background you can list (even outside of CS or programming) that are more helpful in communicating that, and would therefore be a better use of the space.

Are you trying to show that you write good quality code? In that case, the size of the project isn't that important, but having the code publicly available for inspection (e.g. on GitHub) is.

As noted in [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/67756/37509), you should be prepared to talk about what you've listed on your resume in an interview, and it should be clear what your level of involvement in a team project is.